# Execute Job of Jenkins Multijob Plugin from each "position"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am a big fan if the [Jenkins Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin).

I create many “template jobs” like checkout, compile, test, generate archive. I also create for each VM a master job which reuse the templates with different parameters.

So if a master job is triggered it will execute the template jobs in a order like:

- Checkout
- Compile
- Test
- Generate archive
- Upload archive

But the problem is, that I always have to start with checkout but I like to start sometimes with test or sometimes with generate archive. But I do not know how this is possible.

My idea is I create 1 parameter `start_job` and one “dynamic” parameter `current_job` and before a template do his main work it will increment `current_job`, check if `current_job==start_job` and do his main work or do nothing and continue with the next template.

Comment: I have implemented my idea and it is working fine. The disadvantage is, you can only use it for jobs which have build steps. If you got a job which only check out from a repository will always be executed, because the check run later.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible.

I verified it with the plugin author. they may add it.

The workaround (ugly) solution for now is to disable the jobs that you don't want to run again.

Comment: Is there any task where I can see the progress of this feature?